# Actualizar array y eliminar duplicados

Tags: javascript, array

llevo todo el día intentando la manera pero no lo consigo.
Mi problema es el siguiente, en Node-RED estoy sacando un array y me gustaría eliminar los duplicados y quedarme con los que no están repetidos.
[image: Array]

Lo que quiero hacer es que los datos que no estén repetidos se actualicen en una base de datos.
Podemos ver en la imagen que en el primer array (msg.payload[0]) tenemos 63 registros y en el segundo (msg.payload['1']) tenemos 9. La cosa es que en el array 2 ya tiene algunos datos del 1, y pues me tendría que queda con un total de 63-9=54, para meterlos en la bbdd.

Estos son los campos de los datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para acceder a cada campo sería msg.payload[0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3AMF.png).device y así con cada uno.
He probado con estos 2 códigos pero no va:

```
var local = msg.payload[0];
var rc = msg.payload[1];

/*var local = msg.payload[0];
var rc = msg.payload[1];
var conta = 0;

if(local.length != rc.length){
    for(var i = 0; i <local.length-1;i++){
        if(local[i] != rc[conta] ){
            msg.topic = "INSERT INTO datos VALUES('"+local[i].device+"','"+local[i].id+"','"+local[i].mac+"','"+local[i].unit+"','"+local[i].type+"','"+local[i].time+"','"+local[i].val+"')";
        }
        conta++;
    }
}*/




var array = [];
for (var i = 0; i < local.length; i++) {
    var igual=false;
    for (var j = 0; j < rc.length & !igual; j++) {
        if(local[i]['device'] == rc[j]['device'] && local[i]['id'] == rc[j]['id'] && local[i]['mac'] == rc[j]['mac'] && local[i]['unit'] == rc[j]['unit'] && local[i]['type'] == rc[j]['type'] && local[i]['time'] == rc[j]['time'] && local[i]['val'] == rc[j]['val']){
            igual=true;
        }
    }
    if(!igual)array.push(local[i]);
    msg.topic = "INSERT INTO datos VALUES('"+local[i].device+"','"+local[i].id+"','"+local[i].mac+"','"+local[i].unit+"','"+local[i].type+"','"+local[i].time+"','"+local[i].val+"')";
}
msg.payload = array;
return msg;
```

Comment: Te recomendaría leer [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicate-values-from-js-array) es muy completa y sencilla de entender además de que abarca varios casos

Answer (score 0):

Para descartar los elementos duplicados puedes solucionarlo con el método filter para obtener solo los datos que pasen por la condición.

```js
const arr = [
    { name: 'Miguel'},
  { name: 'Juan'},
  { name: 'Carlos'},
  { name: 'Lol'},
  { name: 'Jake'},
  { name: 'Denis'},
  { name: 'lola'},
]

const arr2 = [
    { name: 'Miguel'},
  { name: 'Juan'},
  { name: 'Alejandro'},
  { name: 'Mariela'}
]
let concat = [...arr, ...arr2] // o => arr.concat(arr2);
console.log(concat.filter( (v, i, a) => a.findIndex( t =>( t.name === v.name) ) === i))
```

En el ejemplo utilizamos un filtro en el cual con el metodo findIndex encontraremos el index del item en el array que coincida según el nombre del item actual, (el método findIndex permite encontrar el index de un objeto en un array según sus propiedades y puedes utilizar cualquier propiedad de tu objeto para esto, ej. array.id) luego revisamos si el index encontrado coincide con el index del objeto en la condición de filter, si el index es el mismo pasara de lo contrario se filtrará.

> **[EDIT]** Nótese que los dos arrays deben estar unidos o concatenados antes de pasarlos por el filtro (pensé que era obvio), fíjate que en el ejemplo se unen de la siguiente manera `let concat = [...arr, ...arr2] // o => arr.concat(arr2);` y el nuevo array es el que se procesa, no es que filtramos el primero o el segundo por separado.

Pero esto funciona con una sola o múltiples propiedades si las añades a la condición, pero si quieres filtrar por todos los elementos de un objeto para saber si absolutamente todas las propiedades son iguales puedes hacer lo siguiente, siguiendo mas o menos la misma lógica con filter:

```
concat.filter((v,i,a)=>a.findIndex(t=>(JSON.stringify(t) === JSON.stringify(v)))===i)
```

> Esto podría ser un poco mas lento dependiendo del tamaño del array y cabe destacar que esto no comprueba si las propiedades son duplicadas una por una, si no, si los items son exactamente iguales ya que los transforma en un string para hacer la comprobación.

Una breve explicación de porque la condición del primer filter funciona es que findIndex siempre va a encontrar el primer index que coincida con el contenido del item, siendo que cuando la condición es false el index encontrado es menor al index del objeto actual del filter por lo tanto no entra en el array final.

Espero que te sea de ayuda, un saludo.

Comment: He intentado tu modo pero solo me filtra los datos del primer array, voy a intentar de otra manera, gracias igualmente!

Comment: Como solo filtra los datos del primer array? si los dos arrays están concatenados? Filtra los datos que repiten si son iguales, no tiene sentido discriminar cual array debe tener prioridad en persistir la data si lo que quieres es eliminar los datos que se repiten, si hay una dato del array dos que se repite pues se quedará el primer dato que encuentre.

Comment: Fijate que los dos arrays están concatenados por cierto, no es que lo vas a utilizar solo en un array .-. ...

Comment: Te añadí una explicación de la concatenación en la respuesta, igualmente si corres el ejemplo te puedes dar cuenta que sin importar cuantas repeticiones hayan en cualquiera de los dos arrays, en el output no hay ninguna repetición así que la repuesta está correcta a menos que haya algo que no haya entendido, un saludo y suerte!